# Me menu disappeared

Tags: indicator

I am running ubuntu 10.10 with the Indicator Applet Complete. However on logging in today morning, I find that the me menu has disappeared. I removed the indicators completely from the panel and then added it again however I can't get the me menu back. All the other indicators like sound,mail work perfectly. However the Indicator Applet session is missing the me menu.

Any ideas why this might happen? I did not update any indicators recently.

Comment: You did add the Indicator Applet Session to the panel & the me menu is still missing. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the `indicator-me` package is installed. If it was and you added the Indicator Applet Session and the MeMenu was still gone. Try the following:

```
gconftool – -recursive-unset /apps/panel
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

You might need a reboot after that as well.