# A few items are missing from my panel and I'm not sure how to get them back

Tags: panel, memenu

I'm missing both the Me Menu and the Log Out/Shutdown/Restart, etc applet from my panel and I can't find them in the 'Add to Panel' list. The screenshot below shows the current state of my panel. How can I get them both back?

[image]

Comment: You might want this as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18832/how-can-i-change-dropboxs-indicator-applet-icon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click your panel and then click **Add to Panel**

[image]

Scroll down and select **Indicator Applet Session** and then click Add.

[image]

Now **Me Menu** and **Log Out/Shutdown/Restart** applet will be loaded.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that there are items in the panel that (for reasons I don't understand) go away, and they don't appear in the "Add To Panel" picker.  For example, the little sound control widget (the speaker thingy) is simply not listed there.  Same goes for the "log out/change user" widget.  There's a "log out" widget in "Add To Panel", and a separate "switch user", but the original one, once gone, is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the gnome panel by pressing **Alt+F2** and then typing in the command,

```
gnome-panel --replace
```

If that doesn't work try restarting the system. I get this sometimes but when I log off or restart the machine the applets come back. Though I might ask did you uninstall  gwibber recently, because sometime back when I uninstalled gwibber it also removed the me menu since the me menu is dependent on it. If that is the case, then try installing gwibber through the ubuntu software centre and restart the computer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[Me menu disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16398/me-menu-disappeared/16400#16400)

Answer (score 0):

To add/restore at least Shutdown/Log out/Restart button:
on current panel: RightMouseButton 'Add to Panel', then 'Indicator Applet Session'.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following (It happens sometimes):

1. Remove from the panel enough things that you have an empty space to right click into. If you already have an empty space there is not need to remove anything.
2. Right click the panel and click on Add to Panel...
3. The Main menu is called MAIN MENU (Since i did not see it in the picture). The Logout is called Log Out...(Except if you are talking about the logout with other buttons in which case it is the Indicator Applet Session) Both are next to each other in the Add to Panel Window. Gwibber and actually any program that uses the Me Menu can not be removed since they have a relationship with the Me Menu. So if you remove them, the Me Menu goes too.

If for some reason you already did this and they still do not appear (Which also happens, you need to do one of 3 things:

- Reboot the PC to see the changes.
- Change the resolution so the panel gets longer and shows changes.
- Create a new panel above or below (depending on your previous position) and start moving the addons to the other panel.
- Press ALT+F2 and type gnome-panel --replace

Answer (score 0):

you can also type this command in the terminal, but it will restore the panel to stock, without the widgets you had added afterwards:

`rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/panel/`