# Missing Dropbox indicator-applet icon, how do I get it back?

Tags: indicator, icons, dropbox

I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit and wanted to change my Dropbox indicator-applet icon to make it look more uniform with the other icons. I found this suggestion of a PPA and package to try and followed these instructions: [How can I change Dropbox's indicator applet icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18832/how-can-i-change-dropboxs-indicator-applet-icon#answer-18834)

This worked fine, however, after deciding that I didn't like those icons I uninstalled them via a `sudo apt-get autoremove monochrome-icons-extra` then did a ppa-purge on that PPA. I then stopped and started Dropbox and at that point was missing an icon all together. I can click in the empty space where the Dropbox icon should be and get the drop-down menu, so I know Dropbox is running. I also confirmed this buy running `dropbox status` and it returned `idle`. I tried rebooting but that didn't make a difference, the icon still wont show up.

Next I tried reinstalling Dropbox via `sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus-dropbox`, that had no effect. I then tried to completely remove everything and reinstall. To accomplish this I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nautilus-dropbox
rm ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-dist ~/.dropbox-dist-new
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox*
```

I then went to dropbox.com and downloaded the latest .deb and installed it that way and the icon was still missing, ARGH!

Through a little research, I discovered that the PPA installed the icons to to `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/dropboxstatus-*.svg` and that's how it changed the icons. The images aren't there any more (having uninstalled the PPA), but when I checked on my laptop where Dropbox is working fine, there aren't any other icons in that location, either.

What is going on and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the info found in [this dropbox update](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=23621) and the subsequent [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/dropbox-icons-now-respect-your-global-theme-no-more-manually-replacing-them/) article regarding that update, it would seem the files you need are (should be) in

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/status/
```

Also be sure that your per-user setting doesn't ruin things. Check (I think it should be that one anyway) :

```
~/.icons/hicolor/22x22/status/
```

Note:

- I don't have dropbox installed or anything, so this is mostly assumptions combined.
- Depending on your theme, I guess it is possible that the values from hicolor get overwritten.
- That update link at the beginning also contains a tar that holds the icons incase you need them.

Comment: I was finally able to get my icon showing by putting the icons in `~/.icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/dropboxstatus-*.png`.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can gather the icons are in `/usr/share/icons/[theme]/[resolution]/apps/dropbox.png`.

You can confirm that you have them in that location by running `find /usr/share/icons/ -name 'dropbox.png'`.

If they are missing on your machine and present on your laptop, then you can just copy them over and that could just fix it.

* update *
The status icons are in 
`/usr/share/icons/[theme]/status/[resolution]/`

The names of the default status icons are

1. dropboxstatus-busy.png
2. dropboxstatus-blank.png
3. dropboxstatus-busy2.png
4. dropboxstatus-logo.png
5. dropboxstatus-idle.png
6. dropboxstatus-x.png

I hope that helps you narrow down the search.

Comment: This is the application icon, not the indicator-applet icons that show when dropbox is syncing/idle/etc.  This icon is present and I still don't have an an indicator-applet icon.

Comment: I was finally able to get my icon showing by putting the icons in ~/.icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/dropboxstatus-*.png. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i used the dbus-launch method to get the dropbox icon back (see here:
[Dropbox icon in tray is missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182567/dropbox-icon-in-tray-is-missing#))
. However i appended --exit-with-session to the dbus-launch command.
This way i achieved that the dropbox icon is still visible after logount and login. Without that option i got it only when i completely rebooted the system.
Here is the complete command:
dbus-launch --exit-with-session dropbox start -i