# Where are the systray icons for Dropbox in Ubuntu desktop 13.04 (minimal)?

Tags: unity, indicator, dropbox

I reinstalled Ubuntu desktop using the minimal CD image and the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
```

After that I used Ubuntu Software Center to make sure Unity supports application indicators: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfFtE.png.

Everything works great, except for Dropbox. For some reason the icon doesn't appear in the tray, even though the application is running. Steam on the other hand [runs just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uewVW.png), so it seems like there is nothing wrong with the tray itself.

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/23606/199262) the tray icons should be in `/usr/shared/icons/hicolor/22x22/status` but it doesn't contain any Dropbox icons. Neither do any of the other resolutions. The answer is a bit outdated, so I'm not entirely sure it is still applicable to the current version of Dropbox.

I did the usual thing of reinstalling dropbox with:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

But that didn't solve anything either.

Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this solution from [How To Solve: No Dropbox Icon In Ubuntu 13.10](http://itsfoss.com/solve-dropbox-icon-ubuntu-1310/)

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

I'm currently trying it.  It worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me.