# How to fix this error I got while Re-installing dropbox?

Tags: command-line, uninstall, dropbox, reinstall

How can I fix this error I got while re-installing dropbox?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/411809/nautilus-dropbox-depends-dropbox-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found the answer in the following post
https://askubuntu.com/a/432485

Note the "sudo apt-get autoremove" which allows you to remove packages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

so that you can do as follows to remove any broken packages.

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get upgrade    
sudo apt-get remove dropbox    
sudo apt-get install dropbox
```