# No Dropbox icon in the indicator panel?

Tags: indicator, startup, dropbox

I have recently installed Ubuntu  on my machine and everything has been working fine, except I don't see the Dropbox indicator. I have installed and re-installed Dropbox multiple times and can confirm that it's running in the background (with `ps -e | grep dropbox`).

Does anyone know how to get it back?

Comment: Please [don't change your title to Solved](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7413/attaching-solved-to-title-of-questions-with-accepted-answers)

Comment: I found this solution to work for me in 2016, 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Found a solution at the [comment #7 from the Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1211066/comments/7):

1. Install package
   `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`
2. Log out, and then log back in (or issue `dropbox stop && dropbox start` at the command line)

Note: this method is still applicable in 2021 year, it fixes the problem with Dropbox icon in Ubuntu MATE 21.10.

Comment: do you have any [references](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1211066/comments/7)?

Comment: I've tried executing "dropbox stop && dropbox start" automatically after resume using a script I put in '/etc/pm/sleep.d/'. The log says it is working just fine, but the dropbox indicator is still missing. Thus if I want to see the dropbox icon I have to execute this command manually after resume...

Comment: In 15.10 installing this extra package makes the Dropbox icon show up in the KDE system tray.

Answer (score 7):

If I recall correctly there is an unfixed bug in the dropbox package for 13.10. Cf. [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1211066). This is at present a confirmed, but unassigned bug.

If this is not that bug, then read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23590/missing-dropbox-indicator-applet-icon-how-do-i-get-it-back).

Comment: Answer in the above publication.

Answer (score 6):

There is another issue that has popped up recently.
This is with regard to **14.04**, being that, 
**Dropbox runs in the background but does not show the indicator panel icon** even when **appindicator1 is installed**.

The only work around i found was to re-install Dropbox by getting the **.deb** file form the link: [Download Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)

Comment: worker but needed a reboot

Comment: This bug also in Debian 8.

Comment: I have this problem now , early 2016 and this solution is not working

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Denilson dropbox stop && dropbox start worked for me - but only until next reboot.

Solved it permanently by writing a short shell script (which i put into /opt directory):

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 60s
dropbox stop && dropbox start -i &
```

(mark as executable) and then click on the Ubuntu button on the left upper corner, type "startup" and there add an entry to call that start that shell script /opt/dropboxrestart.sh.

Comment: Nice solution. You can also combine this into one line `sleep 60s && dropbox stop && dropbox start &` and put directly into command field in Startup Applications

Comment: I have this problem now I'm using SSD instead of hard drive - must be a timing issue as there is no problem when I use hard drive. I found I could not just modify command of dropbox Startup Application because next time dropbox starts, it just overwrites it. Also I had to add a sleep between the stop and start as the stop returns well before it actually stops. I created /usr/local/bin/dropbox_delayed which does `sleep 60 && dropbox stop && sleep 60 && exec dropbox start`and created new Startup Application DropboxDelayed which has command dropbox_delayed. Works fine for me.

Comment: Also, I could not put multiple commands in Startup Application command i.e. `sleep 60 && dropbox stop` etc. Does not work (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 3):

As of ubuntu 14.04 do this to put dropbox icon on menu bar :

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

You can start Dropbox from your applications menu.

***UPDATE***

issue this to view what Ubuntu package is involved

```
dpkg -l|grep dropbox
```

... output

```
ii  dropbox   2015.10.28    amd64   cloud synchronization engine - CLI and Nautilus extension
```

so now dropbox package description gives mention of nautilus ... so lets view all files listed in that package ... issue

```
dpkg -L dropbox
```

sure enough it lists files which are nautilus related ... so to answer your comment - I would say the normal dropbox package does contain customizations for integration with nautilus so that stand along package nautilus-dropbox is no longer necessary

Comment: well, I can start it from the menu, but the icon stil does not show up. I guess that is what I get when using beta versions of 14.10 ...

Comment: It not solves the problem

Comment: Can anyone explain the relation between the dropbox package and the nautilus-dropbox package?  And as a bonus, the relation of these two to Dolphin and nautilus?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice workaround, as clean as a workaround can be -- but it *is* just a workaround. I put the critical command "dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start" in my startup file and set the dropbox autostart option to "n" (which might not really be necessary). Now I have the Dropbox icon on the menu bar at the bottom of the screen, and this solution survives a reboot.

Comment: Awesome, this worked wonderfully (on Kubuntu 14.04.5)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 14.04 with Gnome 3. None of the above solutions did work for me.

A solution that worked finally was to install a gnome extension 'topicons'
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/