# Dropbox icon disappears on restart

Tags: 12.04, icons, panel, dropbox

The dropbox icon is not displaying on the indicator panel in the top right hand corner. I tried to implement [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/359224/242873) and it works temporarily after I start and stop dropbox as suggested. However, upon restart dropbox starts up but its icon is nowhere to be found.