# Dropbox icon corrupted on Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: xubuntu, indicator, dropbox

I installed the latest version of **Dropbox** from the official site but when it starts the icon on the indicator appears **corrupted**:

[image]

I don't have any way to set preferences or watch progress, however it seems that Dropbox is **correctly syncing** my documents.
zI already tried a lot of other [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358913/no-dropbox-icon-in-the-indicator-panel/359224#359224) but none of them worked, my OS is **Xubuntu 15.10**.

Thanks!

**EDIT 02/15/2016**

I already tried stopping and restarting the service but it didn't help.
My question **is not a duplicate** of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562259/dropbox-icon-in-the-wrong-place) for the following reasons:

- I am using Xubuntu, not Ubuntu
- In Xubuntu the icon is in the "Indicator Plugin" panel item and I can't edit its properties directly
- The answer seems quite old (more than one year ago)

Comment: So this is a purely aesthetical problem? Have you tried changing your icon theme?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this is not just an aesthetical problem because I can't click on that icon, it is completely broken and non functional. Changing the theme simply shows the "icon not found" icon from the selected theme.

Comment: Try tweaking with Xfce's panel settings/item. Whisker menu > "Preferences" button > Panel > Items. Double click items to see their settings.

Comment: Hi stock, if you quit dropbox and restart, is it fixed? Please let me know. If so, we can fix it.

Comment: @EduardoCola the icon is in the "Indicator Plugin" item and so I can't edit the properties for the single icon, but for the whole panel item only.
JacobVlijm I tried restarting the service many times but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by kk78 in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64) post, there is now an **even better answer** that doesn't have the sudo side effects:

```
dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start
```

So I **copied*** my desktop entry:

```
cp ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop ~/.config/autostart/start_dropbox.desktop
```

Changed the entry like this (please notice the `env` word):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
#Exec=dropbox start -i
Exec=env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

And disabled Dropbox's autostart:

```
dropbox autostart n
```

* you cannot just edit it because Dropbox replaces the file every time you log in.

Comment: WOW, very insteresting. I solve this in other form: Xubuntu 15.10 Dropbox Icon Fail  (http://askubuntu.com/questions/732816/xubuntu-15-10-dropbox-icon-fail/744500#744500)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **Juan M. Gonzalez**, as written in [this](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205683966-Taskbar-Icon-disappeared-KDE4-Linux) post, a **temporary** but working solution is the following:

```
dropbox stop
sudo dropbox start # please notice the sudo!
```

**EDIT 02/16/2016**

Please note that this solution is still working (and I'm still using it) but **it has side effects with file permissions**. Please look into this thread for a list of proposed solutions:

[Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64)

Comment: There are additional details on the bug and two temporary workarounds, and also **important** details on files affected by *sudo*, at the related question: [Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/734886/506976).